# combinign two sql script

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am selecting from couple of tables:

```
 SELECT  SUM(S2.F64)   as sumAll
 FROM someTABLE1 S1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN someTABLE2 S2 ON S2.F32 = S1.F32 
 WHERE S2.F01 = '1006'
 and S2.F68='ORDER' AND S1.F67='ITEM'
```

now I want to get the value of S1.F01 from another select: something like this

```
SELECT S3.F01
FROM someTABLE3 S3
WHERE "something..."
```

So I want something like this:

```
SELECT  SUM(S1.F64) as sumAll, S3.F01  
FROM someTABLE3 S3
LEFT OUTER JOIN someTABLE1 S1 ON S1.F01 = S3.F01
LEFT OUTER JOIN someTABLE2 AS S2 ON S1.F32 = S2.F32 
WHERE S1.F01 = S3_F01
and S2.F1068='ORDER' AND S1.F1067='ITEM'
```

However I want to get all the items in S3 and just fill the column in sumAll where the condition matches.

SO i want something like this(pseudo code):

```
SELECT * from S3
FOR EVERY (S3.F01)
{
    SELECT * FROM S1
    if(S1.F1067='ITEM')
        RETURN S3 AND SUM(S1.F64)
    ELSE 
        RETURN S3
}
```

Is there anyway to do that ?

Comment: I can't understand very well your requirement, but when you have one aggregate function like SUM and you want other columns, you have to group by that other column. But i can't understand if that is what you want. Maybe add table schemmas, some sample data and an expected result to help us help you.

Comment: so here is a simplified pseudo code, Edited the question

Comment: i added an answer. see if it fits your needs. Otherwise, maybe add the structure and some sample data to [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) to make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not absolutely sure that i understood you completely, but here's an approach to do that:

```
SELECT  S3.*, SQ.sumValue
FROM someTABLE3 S3
LEFT JOIN( SELECT F01,SUM(F64)
          FROM someTable1
          WHERE F1067='ITEM'
          GROUP BY F01) SQ ON SQ.F01 = S3.F01
LEFT JOIN someTable1 AS S1 ON S1.F01 = S3.F01
LEFT JOIN someTABLE2 AS S2 ON S1.F32 = S2.F32  AND S2.F1068='ORDER'
```

You do an inner query where you get the `SUM(F64) GROUP BY F01` on `table1`. This way, when you do the `LEFT JOIN` from `table3` to that, you get all of `table3` and K or the `SUM` you want.

Then for the `LEFT JOIN` with `table2`, i do a `LEFT JOIN` with `table1` first since i don't know if you can relate `table2` to `table3`.

This is a little confusing, but i hope you understand the approach

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT  SUM(S1.F64) as sumAll, S3.F01  
FROM someTABLE3 S3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN someTABLE1 S1 ON S1.F01 = S3.F01
    LEFT OUTER JOIN someTABLE2 AS S2 ON S1.F32 = S2.F32 
WHERE S2.F1068='ORDER' AND S1.F1067='ITEM'
GROUP BY S3.F01
```

Edit - move the where criteria to the joins...

```
SELECT  SUM(S1.F64) as sumAll, S3.F01  
FROM someTABLE3 S3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN someTABLE1 S1 ON S1.F01 = S3.F01 AND S1.F1067='ITEM'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN someTABLE2 AS S2 ON S1.F32 = S2.F32 AND S2.F1068='ORDER'
GROUP BY S3.F01
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f089f/3)

Comment: No not really, So what I want is to select everything from S3 (whether the condition S1.F1067='ITEM' matches or not ) and then only have the summation from the table S1 where S1.F1067='ITEM'

Comment: Nop it again gives me only the rows where S1.F1067='ITEM'